# Running processes using the Process class of C# in a safe and restricted manner

Tags: c#, sandbox

I have a WCF service that executes a **.NET exe** file or a **JAVA .class** file by using the **Process** class available in C#.

***Sample code that executes a class file by starting a new process:***

```
 public bool Run(string classFilePath, string[] commandLineParameters)
    {
        var process = new Process { StartInfo = this.GetProcessStartInfoForExecution(classFilePath) };

        try
        {
            process.Start();
            process.WaitForExit();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception("Process start caused an exception");
        }

        if (process.ExitCode != 0)
        {
            this.WriteErrorToFile(classFilePath, process.StandardError.ReadToEnd());

            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

I have read that **AppDomain** class can be used to sandbox and run assemblies in a safe environment, with the problem being that it can only be used for managed code.

So, my question is, is there a way to run processes from C# in a safe and restricted manner not just for .net assemblies, but for any process started using the Process class.

By safe and restricted, I mean restricting accesses to files, resources and preventing the execution of any malicious code.

Thanks-

Comment: Run code in vm configured without network access,wipe image after completion. The rest is compromise that you need clearly define...(almost seriously)

Comment: There are a host of reasons why this isn't a great idea, not the least of which is that you probably don't want an interactive prompt to hang your service.

Comment: @PrestonGuillot: Agreed. As a next step, I was also looking at the possibility of limiting the time span of the process. I thought of taking that up, after tackling the above mentioned problem.